# How can I get the hostname of the machine I work on?

Tags: shell, script

I am wondering how can I get the hostname (fully qualified domain name) of the machine I am working on?

Here is my script:

```
 #! /bin/sh    
 hostname=$(host $ipaddr | awk '{print substr($NF,1,length($NF)-1)}')
 echo $hostname
 $h= get the current hostname
 if [ $hostname -ne $h ]
 then
//instructions
 fi
```

Comment: `hostname -s` should get the short (minus rest of FQDN) hostname... i.e. `hostname=$(hostname -s)`... ?

Comment: `$HOST` environmental variable contains a hostname of the machine.

Comment: Can the OP update the question as to whether they want the FQDN or just the "short" hostname?

Comment: yes, i need  fully qualified domain name.

Comment: echo $HOST display nothing

Comment: resolved with hostname -f, please how can modifiy this condition: $h= get the current hostname if [ $hostname -ne $h ] Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use **`hostname`** or `uname -n` to get the *kernel* hostname (nodename).

`hostname -s` will give just the first component of the same.

Use **`hostname -f`** to get the FQDN – it additionally tries to translate the hostname to an IP address, then back to a domain name.

Comment: resolved with hostname -f, please how can modifiy this condition: $h= get the current hostname
 if [ $hostname -ne $h ]      Thanks a lot.

Comment: [`h=$(hostname -f)`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst)

Comment: var=$(hostname -f)
    echo $var
    if [ $hostname -ne $var ]
[: Illegal number:

Comment: if [ "$hostname" != "$var" ]  works fine :) Thanks a lot. Bests.

Answer (score 3):

Using an environment variable may be tricky.It might be a matter of the shell you're using: some shells use $HOST, others use $HOSTNAME. I would go with the uname -n option that @grawity mentioned.